# Несколько верных ответов в if

Tags: javascript

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
    alert("Отгадай загадки");
    var b = prompt('Мягкие лапки, а в лапках-цап-царапки:');
    var a = 0;
    if (b == 'Кот' ; 'Кошка') {
        alert("Верно");
        a = a + 1
    }
    else {
        alert("неверно");
    }
    alert("Верных ответов=" + a);
    alert("Конец");
</script>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы оба ответа `Кот` и `Кошка` были правильными?

Comment: `(b=='Кот' || b=='Кошка')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используй логический оператор (`||`), который читается как **ИЛИ**, т.е

```
if (b=='Кот' || b=='Кошка') равен if (b равен 'Кот' ИЛИ b равен 'Кошка')
```

Будет полезно знать, что существует еще оператор (`&&`), который читается как **И**, т.е если тебе нужен кот и кошка ВМЕСТЕ, то используй **И**

```
if (b=='Кот' && c=='Кошка') равен if (b равен 'Кот' И c равен 'Кошка')
```

Есть еще один оператор (`!`), который читается как **НЕ**, если тебе нужны все животные, кроме кошки, то здесь используй **НЕ**

```
if (b!='Кошка') равен (b НЕ равен 'Кошка')
```

Это правда не все, но, думаю, пока этого будет вполне достаточно

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/logical-ops

Comment: А в чём проблема с моей правкой?

Comment: Не стоит забывать, что SO - это не форум и не чат, а база знаний, поэтому, как по мне, здесь применим официально-деловой стиль.  По поводу форматирования кода спорить не буду, ибо единого стандарта, насколько я знаю, нет. Экономией пробелов и переводов строк многие занимаются. По поводу форматирования ("кот", "кошка", "равен") - опять-таки, по-моему, текущий вариант хуже моего. А ошибки в написании слов и расстановке знаков препинания - объективно есть ошибки.

Comment: Ещё один момент: ссылку не найду сейчас, но где-то написано, что ваш вклад в SO становится общим и вы не можете говорить: "мой стиль, ничего в тексте не трогайте". Откат к старой версии, которая, по моему мнению (думаю, не только по моему), является более плохой в плане оформления, можно расценивать как вандализм.

Comment: @Regent я все равно не согласен. Какая там не была бы база знаний, тем не менее здесь публикуются авторские ответы. А я как автор могу быть неграмотным, ошибаться в правописании, нести чушь и называть всех чуваками, в этом есть мой стиль как автора. Поэтому пока на SO не введут только копирование ответов с более авторитетных источников чем я, я буду публиковать ответы в таком формате. Да, возможно, я еще молод, и тебе с таким багажом знаний смешно читать мое мнение, но оно таким есть. На SO итак довольно много введено глупых ограничений.

Comment: @dDevil вы можете ошибаться, а другие участники имеют право улучшать ваши посты, исправляя ошибки оформления, и/или голосовать против некорректных постов. Вы в компании незнакомых людей тоже называете их "чуваками"? При обращении в гос. учреждение? На SO немало ограничений для создания содержимого высокого качества. Полгода назад, кстати, было уже обсуждение правок как раз в стиле "моё, не трогайте". Прочитайте, пожалуйста, на досуге: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660

Comment: @Regent ну, если бы другие участники имели право исправлять посты, то автору бы не приходило бы оповещение о редактировании с возможностью отката, т.е какая бы не была бы величина твоей репутации, у руля все же автор. С правкой я ознакомился и увидел ничего, что могло возбудить спор в таком масштабе. Ну ды если вам реально жалко за те 2 балла репутации, которые вы потеряли из-за отката, пожалуйста, но я все еще не вижу объективности в вашей правке. .

Comment: @Regent Ну и да, если вам реально круто вкладывать в сервис, который дает бесполезные нарисованные конфетки за трату личного времени, то займитесь лучше постами с несвязным текстом от новичков

Comment: @Regent, Вам бы следовало продолжить эту дискуссию не в комментариях ответа, а в личном чате.

Comment: @dDevil, я бы тоже Вам советовал обращаться ко всем пользователям в ответах на Вы. Это, во-первых, уважение к тому или иному пользователю; во-вторых, смотрится более красиво.

Comment: @Yuri и что же вас побудило ввязаться в дискуссию, которая проходила полтора года назад? Я и так обращаюсь на "вы", а "Вы" - на мой взгляд, уже перебор. Цитата с http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/51-rubric-88: _"Употребление местоимения 'вы' вместо 'ты' при обращении к одному лицу само по себе уже представляет проявление уважительного отношения к этому лицу. Окончательное решение о написании 'Вы' с прописной (для подчеркивания этого уважительного отношения) принимает автор текста."_

Comment: @Regent, кто-то поднял вопрос и я заглянул. А тут дискуссия. Вот и вмешался :)

Answer (score 9):

Воспользуйтесь оператором или (`||`):

```
if( b=='Кот' || b=='Кошка')
```

либо конструкцией `else if`:

```
if( b=='Кот'){
    ....
}else if(b=='Кошка'){
    ....
}else{
    // Не кошка и не кот.
}
```

либо `switch`:

```
switch(b){
    case 'Кошка':case 'Кот':
        ...
    break; 
    default://Не кошка и не кот.
        ...
}
```

или

```
switch(b){
    case 'Кошка':
        ...
    break;
    case 'Кот':
        ...
    break; 
    default://Не кошка и не кот.
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (b == 'Кот' || b == 'Кошка') {
```

Используйте логические операции. `||` - логическое ИЛИ

Answer (score 3):

Лучше проверять без учета регистра ввода. Регулярным выражением немного сложнее выглядит:

```
if (a.match(/^ко(т|шка)$/i))
```

Зато в отличие от прямых сравнений реагирует на `Кот`, `КОТ`, `КоТ`, `КоШКа` и т.п. Немного усложнив выражение, можно и котят сюда добавить.

Или, для более простого чтения:

```
if (a.match(/^(кот|кошка)$/i))
```

Или, как предлагают в комментариях ниже, заранее перевести текст в нижний регистр и проверить обычным сравнением:

```
var b = prompt('Мягкие лапки, а в лапках-цап-царапки:').toLowerCase();
if (b == 'кот' || b == 'кошка') ...
```

Comment: это излишне. Проще сделать `b.toLowerCase()` и сравнивать с 'кот' и 'кошка', эффект будет тот же, а код проще для восприятия и человеком, и компилятором.

Answer (score 0):

`if (b == 'Кот' || b == 'Кошка')`, в котором используется логическое **ИЛИ** (`||`)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что вы поставили `;` а надо `||`(логический или) а также указать переменную

```js
    alert("Отгадай загадки");
    var b = prompt('Мягкие лапки, а в лапках-цап-царапки:');
    var a = 0;
    if (b == 'Кот' || b == 'Кошка') {
        alert("Верно");
        a = a + 1
    }
    else {
        alert("неверно");
    }
    alert("Верных ответов=" + a);
    alert("Конец");
```